# Express.js - Filter a number and a string in the URL

Tags: node.js, filter, express

I would like to know if it is possible to check a specific format (a Regex expression) of a Express.js URL query, in the query itself (without entring the callback.)

Concretely, I would like to perform a different action, depending on if the query URL is a string or a number (like a user id and user name):

```
app.get('/:int', function(req, res){
    // Get user info based on the user id.
}

app.get('/:string', function(req, res){
    // Get user info based on the user name.
}
```

Can I filter numbers in the first parameter of the `app.get`, or is it impossible except doing the test inside the callback:

```
/(\d)+/.test(req.params.int)
/(\w)+/.test(req.params.string)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify a pattern for a named parameter with parenthesis:

```
app.get('/:int(\\d+)', function(req, res){
    // Get user info based on the user id.
}

app.get('/:string(\\w+)', function(req, res){
    // Get user info based on the user name.
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that express could do that. What version has this been introduced in?

Comment: Great Jonathan. Can you provide us a link or the documentation to learn more. Thanks.

Comment: It's not currently a well-documented feature, but you can find it in the source code: [`utils.pathRegexp(...)`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.1.0/lib/utils.js#L245-L282). The `capture` argument in the `replace` is how it's defined.

Answer (score 3):

the express router also accepts regexp as first argument.

```
app.get(/(\d+)/, function(req, res, next) {})
app.get(/(\w+)/, function(req, res, next) {})
```

Comment: Thanks Floby, but how can I use the query parameter as a variable for my callback? In your solution, I can only filter a URL but not use the query value.