# Express.js - Filter a mongodb id in the URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filter, express, node-mongodb-native

This question inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228901/express-js-filter-a-number-and-a-string-in-the-url) but in my case I need to filter MongoId. Is it possible to make filtering easily that the below because I need use it in each route?

```
app.post('/:mongoId(^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$)', function(req, res){
   // Send query based on mongoId
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there, just don't add the `^` and `$` anchors. And the uppercase `A-F` range isn't even necessary since Express seems to match case-insensitive:

```
app.post('/:mongoId([0-9a-f]{24})', function(req, res){
  var id = req.param('mongoId');
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Express API documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB), yes, you can use a regular expression as a path:

> Regular expressions may also be used, and can be useful if you have
>   very specific restraints.

```
app.get(/^\/commits\/(\w+)(?:\.\.(\w+))?$/, function(req, res){
  var from = req.params[0];
  var to = req.params[1] || 'HEAD';
  res.send('commit range ' + from + '..' + to);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but how can I construct regexp for mongodb id checking?

Comment: What is the exact expression you're trying to target? You can always try your regular expressions to see if they capture what you need at http://regexpal.com/